# how to define a function from a string using python

Tags: python, string, function

this is my code :

```
a = \
'''def fun():\n
    print 'bbb'
'''
eval(a)

fun()
```

but it shows error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c.py", line 8, in <module>
    eval(a)
  File "<string>", line 1
    def fun():
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

Comment: Why do you need eval() ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`eval()` with a string argument is only for expressions. If you want to execute statements, use `exec`:

```
exec """def fun():
  print 'bbb'
"""
```

But before you do that, think about whether you really need dynamic code or not. By far most things can be done without.

Comment: In Python3, this is now a function. You may need to pass in a fake locals/globals dictionary, perform the assignment to a known magic value, and do `fun = myFakeLocals['magic_value']`

Comment: @ninjagecko: His code was using Python 2 syntax so I assumed he'd like his response in the same dialect. It's trivial to "port" to Python 3 though, just add parenthesis. No need to pass in locals/globals either.

Comment: oops, indeed you are quite correct; I was confusing it with an alternative method to `locals()[functionName]`, if you didn't know the name `fun` ahead of time

Comment: [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) is not solely for expressions; it's just that `str` arguments must be expressions, but it can also take code objects of arbitrary complexity. If you mix it with [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile), you can `eval` arbitrary code, e.g. `eval(compile(mystr, '<string>', 'exec'))` works fine (and works identically on Python 2 and Python 3, unlike `exec`).

Comment: "But before you do that, think about whether you really need dynamic code or not. By far most things can be done without.", Yes, otherwise I would be writing VBScript. "By far most things can be done without.", and would be better done with by being more parallelizable(if C had built in function-to-shellcode precompiler, threads would be much more practical to write without resorting to a higher language or making a global function for every thread proc) and not cluttering global scope with stuff only used once.

Answer (score 3):

Eval evalutes only expressions, while exec executes statements.

So you try something like this

```
a = \
'''def fun():\n
    print 'bbb'
'''
exec a

fun()
```

Answer (score 2):

Non-expression [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) arguments must be [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile)-ed first; a `str` is only processed as an expression, so full statements and arbitrary code require `compile`.

If you mix it with [`compile`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#compile), you can `eval` arbitrary code, e.g.:

```
eval(compile('''def fun():
    print('bbb')
''', '<string>', 'exec'))
```

The above works fine and works identically on Python 2 and Python 3, unlike `exec` (which is a keyword in Py2, and a function in Py3).

Comment: Doing this in python 3.7 returns `None` and not the function object.

Comment: @Jonno_FTW: It's not supposed to return it (`def` is not an expression, it doesn't produce anything assignable), it just adds it to the current scope (local if within a function, global otherwise, and you can optionally pass alternate `dict`s for globals or locals). `eval` is only expected to produce a useful return value when used with strings or with `compile` in `'eval'` mode; in `'single'` or `'exec'` mode, it's not evaluating expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If your logic is very simple (i.e., one line), you could eval a [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions) expression:

```
a = eval("lambda x: print('hello {0}'.format(x))")
a("world") # prints "hello world"
```

As others have mentioned, it is probably [best to avoid `eval`](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html) if you can.